# Dump specific records from a table using SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms, dump

I need to select & dump specific records from my database table using SSMS.
I have tried googling but cant find solution for this scenario.

Comment: Dump where? a text file? another table?

Answer (score 0):

According to [julio-césar](https://serverfault.com/users/1150/julio-c%C3%A9sar)

> In SQL Server Management Studio right-click your database and select
>   Tasks / Generate Scripts. Follow the wizard and you'll get a script
>   that recreates the data structure in the correct order according to
>   foreign keys. On the wizard step titled "Set Scripting Options" choose
>   "Advanced" and modify the "Types of data to script" option to "Schema
>   and data"
>
> TIP: In the final step select "Script to a New Query Window", it'll
>   work much faster that way.

[enter link description here](https://serverfault.com/questions/147638/dump-microsoft-sql-server-database-to-an-sql-script)

Comment: Thanks you! I knew how to use the generate scripts method, but it can be used to dump only the entire table or any database object. I need to dump specific records from a table.

Answer (score 0):

Using command line, you can execute sqlcmd.exe and use -o parameter to put results to a file.

```
sqlcmd.exe -E -d db1 -Q"select * from dbo.t1 where col1 = 'foo'" -o results.txt
```

Or pass in a sql script

```
sqlcmd.exe -E -d db1 -i file1.sql -o results.txt
```

You can also use bcp.exe, using queryout parameter.

Comment: My mistake, you said using SSMS.  After you run your query, go to File in menu bar, there should be an option to save the query and save the results.  It may also help if you tell us what you plan to do with the results.